# chmod 444 can't login

Tags: ftp, chmod

Using proftpd I'd like to login to server. I set permission to user directory to 444. When I am trying to login using ftp client - doesn't working, I can't log in. Did I do something wrong? Maybe I set wrong chmod, it should be read permission to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set execute rights to directory to have access rights to it. So try

```
chmod 555 <directory_name>
```